# Prepend input element within list elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to loop through an ordered list and prepend an input button for each list element (Chrome extension).

I keep getting the following error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.`.

Is it not possible to append a child element within a `<li>` in this fashion? Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
function formatList() {
  const stepsList = document.querySelector("ol.someClass");
  stepsList.childNodes.forEach((step, index) => {
    const checkboxElement = document.createElement("input");
    checkboxElement.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkboxElement.onclick = () => {
      stepsList.removeChild(step);
    };
    step.appendChild(checkboxElement);
  });
}
```

My ideal output structure would look something like this:

```
<ol>
  <li><input type="checkbox"/>Some text here!</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"/>Some text here!</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"/>Some text here!</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Use `[...stepsList.children].forEach` or `for (const step of stepsList.children) {}`

Comment: So the solution is to use `children` as opposed to `childNodes`? I guess `children` returns an object that we spread into the array?

Comment: No, the solution is to convert to an array or to use the new type of loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try with children o retrive only li elements:

```js
function formatList() {
  const stepsList = document.querySelector("ol.someClass");
  console.log(stepsList);
  [...stepsList.children].forEach((step, index) => {
    console.log(step);
    const checkboxElement = document.createElement("input");
    checkboxElement.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkboxElement.onclick = () => {
      stepsList.removeChild(step);
    };
    step.appendChild(checkboxElement);
  });
}

formatList();
```

```html
 <ol class="someClass">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
```